# Select query with IN clause: filling the blanks

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following problem with a MySQL query in C#:

Given a list of strings, I want to query the database for any rows that match said strings. The strings are unique in that each string matches no more than one row. Today, my query looks something like this:

```
SELECT Id FROM SomeTable 
WHERE SomeColumn IN("foo", "bar", "baz")
```

Now, ideally I would like to be able to map the result from the query directly to the list of strings I supplied in the IN clause:

```
String                         Returned ID
------------------------------------------
foo                            123
bar                            NULL        <-- Missing row filled with NULL
baz                            42
```

This works fine as long as all strings I pass to the query match a row. When one is missing, however, I would like to fill in the blank with a NULL as in the example above.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

---

**Edit:** I should probably have pointed out that the solution must scale to a lot of strings. The way I do it right now is that I pass 100 at a time through the IN clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *could* do this:

```
SELECT 
  helper.SomeColumn,
  SomeTable.Id 
FROM  
  (
   SELECT 'foo' AS SomeColumn
   UNION SELECT 'bar'
   UNION SELECT 'baz'
  ) AS helper
  LEFT JOIN SomeTable ON SomeTable.SomeColumn = helper.SomeColumn
```

Of course you can create the helper table (as a temp table) beforehand instead of inline.

Anyway, maybe it is smarter and more efficient to just do the query you have (`WHERE SomeColumn IN (...)`) and simply figure out the missing rows in your application. You will loop over them anyway, so you will notice.

Comment: Thank you -- it certainly sounds like I'm better off doing this in code!

Answer (score 2):

What you could do is `SELECT` the set of strings as a result set and then `LEFT JOIN` on `SomeTable.SomeColumn`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT Id 
    FROM  (
                SELECT "foo" SomeColumn
                UNION ALL
                SELECT "bar" AS SomeColumn
                UNION ALL
                SELECT "baz" AS SomeColumn 
             ) b
             LEFT JOIN 
             SomeTable a
ON  a.SomeColumn = b.SomeColumn
```